# Serial Port receiving "old" data

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Currently using the standard .NET serial port systems to interact with serial (COM) port barcode scanners. The code is reasonably straight forward (combined into one block for ease of reading below). This code works 100% of the time with the 3 or 4 test scanners and PC's I have but seams to cause one or both of the below issues with some users with no discernible hardware or software patterns between affected users.

The application either:

- Receives the data from the previous scan a second time, e.g. physically scan "barcode1" app receives "barcode1", physically scan "barcode2" app receives "barcode1" again !
- or the entire scanner/application appears to be out of sync by one scan e.g. physically scan "barcode1" receive "barcode0", scan "barcode2" receive "barcode1" etc

The return character matches the scanners setup (expecting "\r" for reading and receiving 0d from the scanner port) and the other settings should be correct as other than occasional occurrences of the above the application and scanner interact correctly.

**UPDATE 1**

I've recieved some raw com port logs and it looks like the "1 scan out" issue somehow persisted even after purge commands ("IOCTL_SERIAL_PURGE") are sent. They are sent as part of the "_serialPort.Open()" process.

```
// setup the port class
_serialPort = new SerialPort(Settings.PortName, Settings.Scanner_BaudRate, Parity.None, Settings.Scanner_dataBits, StopBits.One); 
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPort.ReadTimeout = Settings.Scanner_Timeout; 
_serialPort.WriteTimeout = Settings.Scanner_Timeout; 
_serialPort.NewLine = "\r";

// once ready open the port (this gets called each time we attach/detach the scanner)
_serialPort.Open();

// if successful attach the receiving method
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataIn);

// inside the receiver (DataIn)
SerialPort p = (SerialPort)sender;
string data = "###NOSCANN##";
data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
// data string is then sent on to processing
```

Comment: The application has to be started before you start scanning.  You may need to send a command to reader to flush buffer.  Serial port on on your machine should get flushed when the port is opened.  There is also a possibility that the cable you are using has the cts and or rts connected.  So trying a different cable may help.

Comment: Usually barcode scanners act like keyboards, could it be the place you are putting the data has keyboard focus?

Comment: Application is started and looking at a port monitor a flush is being sent as part of the port open process. dont think the cable can be changed in most scanners its just straight into the scanner.

Barcode scanners can either be in keyboard or serial mode, I'm utilising serial mode so no keyboard interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try clearing the read buffer after reading the response in the `DataIn` method. Try something like `_serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();`

Besides that, I would be careful on synchronizing the command transmission and response receival. Before attempting to read the response, you should be sure that there is one available.

```
  public class SerialPortConnection
    {
        private readonly SerialPort serialPort;
        private readonly ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private readonly object mutex = new object();

        public SerialPortConnection(string port, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits,StopBits stopBits, int timeOut)
        {
            serialPort = new SerialPort(port, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits)
            {
                Handshake = Handshake.None,
                ReadTimeout = timeOut,
                WriteTimeout = timeOut,
                NewLine = "\r\n"
            };
            serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
        }

        private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            mre.Set();
        }

        public void OpenPort()
        {
            serialPort.Open();
        }

        public string SendCommand(string command)
        {
            lock (mutex)
            {
                serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                serialPort.Write(command);
                mre.WaitOne();
                string response = serialPort.ReadLine();
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                return response;
            }
        }
```

For ensuring that only one command is sent and a response is received before being able to send a new command, I would use a `lock` statement. Next, for making sure that a response is available to be read before doing so, I would use an instance of the `ManualResetEvent`. After sending the command, I am blocking the execution by using the `WaitOne()` method. When a response is received, the `DataReceived` event is invoked, whose event handler calls the `Set()` method which sets the signaling to true, thus allowing further execution of the code in the `SendCommand()` method.

Please also notice that before writing any data on the transmit buffer I perform a `DiscardOutBuffer()`. Also, after reading the data from the receive buffer I clean it by calling `DiscardInBuffer()`

Comment: Clearing the buffer after readline makes sence so I'll give that a go. 

Im my case since its a barcode scanner I dont have any commands to the device, I just recieve the scan data. As such are the write command sections for the purpose of actully sending meaningful data to the device or a method to help ensure the inbound data is ready by sending some sort of outbound? (e.g. is there any need for the locking and ManualResetEvent if im not going to be sending any data, only recieving?

Comment: In the case that you are not writing to the serial port, you can get rid of the `ManualResetEvent`. You don't have to synchronize read/write operations anymore. Given that you only read data from it when the `DataReceived` event is invoked, I would "protect" the code from the eventhandler from race conditions, using a `lock` system. Imagine that 2 read operations are performed consecutively and rapidly. For the first read operation, the code execution within the `SerialPort_DataReceived` has not finished by the time the code execution starts for the second read operation.

Comment: Therefore, you could do something like this:

 ```private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   lock (mutex) 
   {
        /// ... do your work
   }
}```

Comment: Wouldnt hurt to lock around the main scan event so will add that in aswell.  Also updating main post with some new details

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
_serialPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
```

Comment: This isnt valid in this case as the scanners are configiured to sent \r  ( 0d in the raw scanner data )  so \r\n would cause the scanner to not finish reading the line.

Comment: Can you show the results of serial port output in hyper terminal?